# Is there keyboard shortcut to move input focus to the Google Search box?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I search on Google a lot. I find it very annoying to have to move my mouse to the search box and click once so that I can input another search term.

I did Google for some time, but no one seems to be quite as annoyed with this, surprisingly.

I'm using Firefox 8 and Chrome 16, on Windows 7.

---

If you know Atlassian Confluence, you might probably know that pressing <kbd>/</kbd> will move input focus to the upper right search box, very convenient for a keyboard shortcut hobbyist . Try it [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ALLDOC/Atlassian+Documentation).

[image: Atlassian Confluence provides / as "go to search box" shortcut]

EDIT:

According to slhck's statement. I tried it on several PCs(5+, including virtual machine). The strange thing is that only one of them exhibits the stated behavior. Others(I call them dumb ones) exhibit a weird behavior. Even if I select **Always show instant result** and save, it reverts to **Only when my computer is fast enough**, and the keyboard navigation still does not work.

[image: google preference weird behavior]

Poking around for some moment, I finally managed to make it work. The trick is: Select **Never show instant result** , save, then select **Always show instant result** again. Now it remains there and keyboard navigation works .

Confirmed on Chrome and Firefox, and Windows 7 IE8.

Anyway, don't you think there should be a keyboard shortcut(or any key) to jump to search box no matter instant predication is on or off?

Comment: Is that Confluence thing just an example of how you want it to be? Are you talking about Google search in general?

Comment: I talked about Confluence in order to show to the effect/feature I hope to have on Google's web page, --as an analogy, in case someone cannot understand what I mean.

Comment: I am always amazed that people aren't aware of _CONTROL+K_.  I couldn't survive for 5 minutes without it!

Comment: `/` shortcut does work to me on http://google.com webpage.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/509192/tab-enter-no-longer-taking-me-to-first-google-search-result-in-chrome/554324#554324

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As of 2021, apparently you need to type a slash to get back to the search box.

Google will show this in the bottom-left corner:

[image]

(I didn't get this to work on latest Chrome on macOS with a German keyboard, so your mileage may vary…)

Answer (score 29):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in [Chrome](http://google.com/chrome) not only moves your courser to the Google ommibox, but it also clears it, saving you the extra keystroke.

<kbd>F6</kbd> is another way to get to omnibox, and will **always** work, whereas key combinations may also depend on where your mouse courser or focus is; for example, on SE, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is the shortcut to add code to a question or answer.

Comment: Seems like Ctrl+E is an alternative on SE :) https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+K clears the Omnibox but leaves a question mark for some reason.

Comment: @DMan: the question mark ensures that the text entered is to be **searched**, not gone to.  For example (and to clarify), typing "?www.StackExchange.com" will make a Google search for "www.StackExchange.com".  Its actually a really great feature when you think about it for a minute.

Comment: @wizlog - Oh cool, I didn't know that. Will certainly save me a few keystrokes as I always hit down down a couple times after using Ctrl + L and typing in something I want to _search_.

Comment: On Mac Chrome, Option + Cmd + F clears the address bar and precedes with "?".  Press escape to cancel the clearing of address bar and show the current URL again.  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Comment: As I underderstand the question, "to move my mouse to the search box" means the search box in the Google.com site directly. Your answer set the focus in the Google CHROME address bar (omnibox) that can be used to search too, but it doesn't answers the question. Moving the focus to the Google website search box directly has benefits like using the previous search to add a new

Answer (score 20):

In Google Chrome, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to focus the address bar. This would allow you to perform a new search instantly.

In case you want to focus the search box on the actual Google website, please refer to [slhck's answer](https://superuser.com/a/410817/36744).

You can also enable Instant inside Google Chrome by checking the following setting:
[image]

Comment: I might clarify that this isn't so useful for Firefox in this particular context.

Comment: Oh wow, seems like I completely missed the point of the question :D

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite the same as in-page search box. For example, I first search "ipad gps", but not satisfied with the result, then I want to append "bluetooth". If I use search box, I can just append "bluetooth", but for address bar, I have to key in "ipad gps bluetooth" from the beginning. Also, Google Instant predictions does not work from address bar.

Comment: @ChenJun I understand the solution is not sufficient, sorry. Just for your information though, you can enable Google Instant for Chrome in the settings. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @Shinrai in firefox, you can use Ctrl+K to jump to the upper right search box.

Comment: @houbysoft - Sure, but that's not in this answer, so I fail to see how that's relevant to my comment. :)

Comment: @Chen: But that's not how Confluence's search works. All Confluence's search page seems to do is let you re-focus an empty search box. This would be no different from searching via the address bar or via the Firefox search tool. Also, Google Instant [does work in Chrome's address bar](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=177873). You can also enable this in Firefox using InstantFirefox.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know what you mean by saying "that's not how Confluence's search works" -- maybe because I'm not a web developer. I just want to move keyboard focus onto the search box provided by the webpage by just pressing a key/key-combination instead of forcing me to use mouse.

Comment: @Chen: I was referring to your comment above where you said you wouldn't be able to append "bluetooth" to your search results. The Confluence search doesn't allow you to append new terms to your search string either. It has the key shortcut to take you to the search box, but it clears the search box after each search. So using `Ctrl+L`/`Ctrl+K`/etc. would essentially be the same. Though in the case of the search box, you can just hit `End` to append to the search string.

Comment: @ChenJun When using `CTRL+E`, at least in IE, takes you to the address bar, and replaces the url with `? last-search` which you can then modify. Chrome doesn't remember the search, at least not for me.

Comment: `CONTROL+K` is the best approach for Firefox and Chrome.  It works on all platforms (Linux, Mac, Windows).

Answer (score 7):

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut works for Firefox, I.E. and Chrome (in Windows) to move the focus to the search box (well, in IE and Chrome to the address bar, clear it and start with `?`, which is the same as a search box).

For Ubuntu, Firefox doesn't seem to pay attention to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (at least not for me), but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> works.

Then depending on how you've configured your browser is the search engine that will be used to perform your search.

Comment: +1 on the `?` reference. Also, OP could install vimperator on firefox and just type `:o <searchtext>`

Comment: `CONTROL-K` works for Windows, Ubuntu, AND Mac (COMMAND-K)...

Comment: @jahroy Cool. But not for all browsers. In Windows IE `CTRL`+`K` duplicates a tab. In Win. Firefox it does move to the search field.

Comment: @frozenkoi - That is correct.  I was responding to this: _For Ubuntu, Firefox doesn't seem to pay attention to CTRL+E_.  Obviously there's no IE in Ubuntu (thank goodness).  Either I overlooked your mention of `CTRL+K` or it was added/edited today.  `CTRL+K` works for Firefox and Chrome on all platforms.  `CTRL+L` seems to be the most universal way to get to the address bar (`ALT+D` doesn't always work).

Comment: @jahroy Yeah I added your info into the answer when I saw your comment.

Comment: use COMMAND+L on a mac, not COMMAND+K. That reloads Google.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is probably the shortcut I use the most every day.

It works for Firefox and Chrome on Linux, Windows, and Mac (use the *Command* key on Mac).

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is the equivalent for IE.

For Safari, it's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (far less convenient).

Answer (score 5):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> while on a Google search cycles between selecting all of the current search text and selecting none.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please add a comment when you have enough reputation

Comment: I believe it is an answer: pressing the Esc button cycles between the search box and the rest of the content.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Agreed. This appears to work for me so far. Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> moves focus to the search bar.

Answer (score 2):

I am a heavy `Ctrl+K` (and `Ctrl+L`) user, but this is not sufficient for this use case. Often I want to **adjust my search** with additional refinements. To do this what I found easiest is to use Chrome (instead of Firefox) with the so-called `Vimium` extension, see: http://vimium.github.io/

The key combination that brings you to the search box is `gi`.

Note: This is by the way not the only speed-up you get. I love their way of **addressing links** in the browser, just type `f` and you will have a few letter combinations that bring you to any link on that page. You will never go back.

Comment: Thank you - I don't know why you have been downvoted - this is one and only proper answer here for the question formed like this. I'm adding Vimium to my toolbox :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the search box in a website is not identified in a standard way across all websites, there isn't a dedicated keyboard shortcut to jump straight to it. What you'll have to do is just keep hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go backwards) until you end up in the search box again. These keyboard shortcuts will cycle through all the website's links and input forms.

Some search engines will let you begin typing immediately to do another search if you don't click anything else. Other than the method above, sometimes they'll code their site with some javascript that captures keyboard input. Experiment and see what the site provides.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017-07-31, [Google removed this feature entirely from search](http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674).

I created the [open source Web Search Navigator extension](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator) to fix this and add extra features (like configurable keyboard shortcuts).

See [installation instructions](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator#installation).

Hope you find it useful, but in any case - feedback is welcome!

Comment: I am using this extension and I must say it works great, you can focus search and move around the SERP very easily

Comment: Could not install in Opera.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

### For Google Chrome

**Address Bar**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**Google Search**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

**Search Box of any Website**
Use [Search Box Focus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-box-focus/amgmdnojamodmpfjaokfgpijhpcednjm)

Answer (score 1):

The top voted answer works without installing anything. But it doesn't work for me because if I've disabled some javascript on Google to disable the annoying autocomplete on the searchbox.

This is how to get back the search box shortcut function ...

1. In chrome/firefox, install the [Surfingkeys](https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys) extension.
2. Reload the webpage, and simply press "i" on your keyboard. This will focus the first textbox on the page. Works on google search page, and stackoverflow etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the good answers already posted, you can always install a keyboard macro processor like AutoHotKey in Windows or AutoKey in Linux.  Once you do that, you can define hot keys that do anything you can do from the keyboard (and a lot more) regardless of what the applications or Window manager provide for you.

Comment: I use Autohotkey daily to to Ctrl+V paste into CMD windows etc. But I'm not very versed in it and it seems a bit overkill. Frankly speaking, Autohotkey's syntax is not very elegant and hard to remember so hard to compose. Anyway I'll be thankfull if you can present a workable Authotkey script to do that.

Comment: @JimmChen Sorry, I just know of Autohotkey.  I use AutoKey on Linux.  It rocks, but won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I just type something, it jumps to the Google Search Box. Also Backspace moves to the Google Search Box. The spacebar does something different (it is like pushing PgDn?).

Answer (score 0):

For your intended use case (search, and then search again without using the mouse), you can use 'Esc' which will select the search box again so that you can type.

Comment: The initial question is "Is there keyboard shortcut to move input focus to the Google Search box?". The answer is yes: the Esc key moves focus to the Google Search box. How is that not an answer? Or did you not realize that "select the search box again" is synonymous with "move input focus to the Google Search box" in this context?

Comment: Go to https://duckduckgo.com/ search "something", type H. That's the question all about but for Google.

Answer (score 0):

Could might try hitting "ESC" and then just start typing; the typing will probably be appearing appended to whatever string you've already typed in the search bar. This works for me on Firefox on OSX.

Also since anything that isn't recognized as a URL is interpreted as a search on my browser (default search set to google.com), if you don't want to append to the text, but, rather, replace it entirely, then you might as well do CNTRL-L (COMMAND-L in OSX) and use the address/search bar combo in Firefox / Google Chrome.

Comment: Go to https://duckduckgo.com/ search "something", type H. That's the question all about but for Google.

Answer (score 0):

I too felt the same way while using the google search box often.

There is no shortcut for such function, But there is another way for it.

You can use the method of using the mouse on the keyboard buttons with the help of **mouse keys** option.

Once you did this, place your cursor over the search engine box and left it untouched.

Now you can press "5" button which is the replacement of a left click in the mouse.

I hope this would be useful when you watch English movies, series (especially The Big Bang Theory) or other videos and you want to find the meaning of any word.

Answer (score 0):

Its 2020, but Google does not support it yet :(. its works very well in Youtube with '/' key and am fan of this.
None of the answers above worked for me through but
Anyhow i found a useful chrome extension you can use to focus google search box and modify search keywords. 
[Quick Focus Search Boxes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-focus-search-boxes/gnnipakmeeinoojnajkonpimknojpbhp)
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a famous trick, before pressing `/`, you must press `,` (just comma without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). Just after pressing `,` and then `/`, you will get the desired result. Also the shortcut will not work before your Google account has fully loaded, that is it's a Google shortucut, not a Chrome shortcut.