# Tab + Enter no longer taking me to first Google search result in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

As the title says; I used to be able to press <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in Chrome to take me to the first search result. This now only works if I am not signed in to my Google account. When signed in, I can't do it. It works fine (signed in and not) on Firefox.

I believe this may have stopped working since a system update.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Chrome 23.0.1271.64

Is this to do with a setting within Google, or is it something within Chrome? Because it works in Firefox, it suggests it is a Chrome problem. I tried disabling all extensions, but no joy.

Comment: I have windows chrome v. 23.0.1271.64 m and same problem. So you can remove the ubuntu flag I think. The problem comes and goes it seems, that is I've experienced the problem before, and now the problem reappeared perhaps a week or two ago. Perhaps it should become a chrome bugreport? I havn't tried logging out, but in incognito the tab+enter also works for me (to browse to first hit)

Comment: Yes, I get the same thing, it works in incognito. It's strange that it works even not in incognito as long as I'm not signed in...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These no longer work as Google have removed this feature, so you can't just turn it out like you used to be able to. The way you *used* to be able to do this was through:

Google Search > Settings > Search Settings > Google Instant Prediction > On

but it no longer works. I was so sad to see this feature go that I wrote a hack to re-engineer it. So far it only works with Google Chrome, but can be adapted to work with all the others:

1. Install Chrome extension [ShortKeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck).
2. Click on the ShortKeys menu and select "Options"
   [image]
3. Click on "Add" and fill in the following fields:

**Keyboard Shortcut:** tab

**Behavior:** Run JavaScript

**Label as:** Result Picker

4. Paste the following JavaScript into the **JavaScript code to run:**

   ```
   document.selectedResultId=0

   function selectResult(newId){
       els = document.querySelectorAll("div.r h3")
       if(newId < 0 || newId >= els.length)
           return  //Could modify for page nav...?
       rp = document.getElementById("result-pointer")
       if(rp != null){
           rp.remove()
       }
       document.selectedResultId=newId
       el = els[newId]
       lnk = el.parentElement
       el.innerHTML = "<div id=\"result-pointer\" style=\"position:absolute;left:-15px;\">&gt;</div>" + el.innerHTML
       lnk.focus()
   }
   document.onkeyup=function(event){
       if(event.keyCode==38)
           selectResult(document.selectedResultId-1)
       if(event.keyCode==40)
           selectResult(document.selectedResultId+1)
       if(event.keyCode==13){
         var el = document.querySelectorAll("div.r h3")[document.selectedResultId]
         var lnk = el.parentElement
         var url = lnk.href
         if(event.ctrlKey){
           var win = window.open(url,"_blank")
           win.blur()
           window.open().close()
         }
         else{
           document.location = url
         }
       }
   }
   selectResult(0)
   ```

   5. Configure the **Activation Settings**:

**Active while in form fields** (Checked)

**Websites** (Only specific sites)

**URLS (one per line)**: *www.google.*

This is what the Options page should look like

[image: ShortKeys Options Page]

6. Click Save and then close your browser.

***Instructions:***

- When you restart you should see a little blue (or black) ">" appear by search
  results when you hit tab.
- The up/down arrow keys make it cycle through the results.
- Hitting "Enter" will navigate to the highlighted result.
- Hitting "Ctrl+Enter" to open the result in a new tab.

Happy Searching!

Comment: This is very very good! If you repeat this answer on my new question here I'll accept it as the answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1234766/how-to-use-keyboard-to-navigate-google-search-results-now-that-instant-search-i

Comment: I'm not sure if I should change the accepted answer here - the accepted one was correct at the time of writing, but is now out of date given that instant search has been killed off

Comment: You should accept whichever answer you feel will be most useful to the community.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill - please do not post the same comment to multiple answers.

Comment: @Robino you realise he is a mod, right?

Comment: @BillCheatham I say make this the accepted answer as it is now the most useful and relevant answer to the question. The rest are now irrelevant / history.

Comment: @Burgi Are you implying mods don't read comments and that I waste my time responding? Or is it something more insightful?

Comment: I was implying that he knows what he is doing. Needlessly antagonising them isn't wise. DON'T FEED THE MODS!

Comment: ok, I see what you mean - I agree this is not the forum for such discussion. Better to take it on Meta.

Comment: I recommend using \*www.google.\* so that `tab` key will continue working on calendar, inbox, and such

Comment: @JoeyBaruch I updated my answer - Thank you!

Comment: An updated version of this script and instructions are being actively maintained at https://github.com/RobinH-J/SearchingShortcuts

Answer (score 24):

This can be fixed by editing your search preferences, or the cookie that is set for them.

In my case it was caused by google instant being set to off. Turning it back on returned the 'tab to first result', and the 'up and down arrow keys to cycle through results' behaviours.

Others found deleting the relevant cookie worked. It's something to do with search prefs in general, as I get the desired behaviour in incognito mode even when google instant is on.

See google product forums [post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/39zuiz__6Nw) for discussion.

== UPDATE ==

I've just found that merely opening an incognito / private window and then closing it restores this behaviour for normal windows when it's stopped working.

Comment: Turning Instant Predictions on in Search settings worked for me.

Comment: "Only when my computer is fast enough" does not work, you must choose "Always show Instant results".

Comment: I am wondering how Google Instant was ever turned off for me. I am *sure* that I never turned it off manually.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Every few weeks or so, it automatically turns off for me. It has happened for years and it's incredibly frustrating. I've never figured out the cause.

Comment: 3 years later I can confirm: You have to activate "Google Instant Predictions" (like described in _Soheil's_ answer)

Answer (score 11):

You need to enable "Google Instant predictions"

From Search Result Page > Settings > Search Settings > Google Instant predictions > On

Comment: Having multiple Google accounts (Apps for Work + regular) I noticed it worked for some. Google Instant-predictions indeed made the difference. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, as in 2019, this feature is no longer available...

Answer (score 7):

As of 2017-07-31, [Google removed this feature entirely from search](http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674).

I created the [open source Web Search Navigator extension](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator) to fix this and add extra features (like configurable keyboard shortcuts).

See [installation instructions](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator#installation).

Hope you find it useful, but in any case - feedback is welcome!

Comment: Thank you for doing this.  Dismayed at the change and glad to have this easy fix.

Comment: This is great! Is it possible to create one for Firefox based on yours?

Comment: I will look into making this cross browser (and perhaps cross search engine) in the future, but I doubt I'll have the resources to do it in the next few weeks. Feel free to send a PR though!

Answer (score 3):

As of now, Google Chrome has this feature re-enabled by default. Upon searching, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and focus will change to the first result link.

This is now called the [Skip to main content](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/181196?hl=en) feature - between key presses you'll see this
[image]

Comment: Seems to have stopped working for me for some reason. Still investigating why...

Comment: Confirmed as working solution: 2020-12-23

Comment: I have been using this too for over a year, but all of a sudden it stopped working. Tab takes me to this box, but pressing enter doesn't take me to the main content. No idea why!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It doesn't require extensions and is simple.

Comment: Now you need to press Shift+Tab 4 times. (oof!)

Answer (score 2):

The [Tab shortcut is no longer available](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171571&topic=25799&ctx=topic). You can, however, configure a search engine shortcut. Click on **Tools -> Settings -> Search -> Manage Search Engines**. Then type in `I'm Feeling Lucky` for Search Engine Name, <kbd>l</kbd> or any other keystroke for the shortcut, and the URL `http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI`.

You can also click on `Make default`: simply type the search query in the `Omnibox` and hit Enter to go to the first result.

Comment: thank you! this advice is the best! i assigned symbol ; as a shortcut to avoid confusion with any letter. now I just type my search like "; kitten video" (without quotes) and it just works! great productivity booster. no plugins required.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Chrome Extension called RESULTER, which provides good search results navigation.

You can download it from Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resulter-shortcuts-for-se/chojfhfgbdaeokblbdeahgbijodikdpk

Comment: Please be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state and perhaps giving someone a visual with confirmation as such, and also be 100% certain that this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post.

Answer (score 0):

That is no shortcut as far as i know, Tab key jumps the selection on screen, when you search and then press Tab+Enter it will be first result always. it might be possible that you have selection somewhere else when you press Tab key.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing since the required keystrokes change depending if you used Chrome's location bar to do the search or using the search box on the Google results page.

**Coming from the location bar**: one can simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>↓</kbd>

**If already on results page** (after an initial search): simply hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Actually, *could* simply always be redundant and just always <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> (but then it almost defies the purpose of shortcut).

(Also, assuming Google Instant predictions settings are on)

edit: oh it appears to work consistently in Firefox by simply tabbing, unlike Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was moved to the DOWN arrow key when searching from the Chrome address bar.

TAB still works, but you need be searching using an already loaded google search page, and you need to have instant results turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a tiny Chrome Extension that only lets you hit TAB key to move results of Google Search. Try it and let me know how's that.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkldgaaaafjoipnomoinnkccihdiffee

Comment: This was working fine until very recently. The new Chrome (Version 69.0.3497.81) now takes me to the number '2' of search result pages, at the very end of the web page, instead of the first result. This estrange behavior disappears when your app is removed from Chrome. Please, report on this, your app was providing a great feature.

Comment: Hi @nightcod3r , thanks for using it. Hmm it seems working fine in my Chrome
Version 69.0.3497.100 . If you can find out how to reproduce it, please tell here.
https://github.com/piglovesyou/google-search-result-focusable/issues/new