# Google Search Engine Results Page Keyboard Navigation

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am aware of the [answer provided here](https://superuser.com/questions/837760/why-cant-i-use-google-search-keyboard-navigation-with-chrome).

If you browse [an official discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/websearch/2Xm9L8kEfUE/-DhDZS1ohKQJ), the only answer that can be found is also to switch on Instant search.

I have a few problems with this. The main one is that Instant limits to 10 results. I want keyboard navigation but I can only get 10 results to navigate with my keyboard. It's like some kind of a joke, except it's not a joke.

Anyway, no animosity toward Google. The very reason that I'm ticked off is testament to the quality of the product itself, after all.

So the real question is, does anyone have a Tampermonkey userscript or Chrome browser Extension that lets me keep Instant off while giving me keyboard navigation?

I found some links from many years ago, but userscripts.org is now defunct. Besides, even if I did find a solution for running in Chrome and Firefox, I use Safari on my Mac, and even with Google Instant search the Tab key doesn't work at all in Safari.

I would cook up my own bookmarklet, I don't want to reinvent a wheel. (and besides, I still don't know how to bind a bookmarklet to run by pressing one key) ---- If I had to resort to doing this, I could do it in under an hour. I don't care how sophisticated or spaghettified a webpage is, a keyboard handler that does something useful can be hacked together in an hour. It boggles the mind how this isn't a feature that exists.

Comment: Hi Steven, have you perhaps hacked something up by any chance or found a different solution for this?

Comment: No I don't and this still pisses me off. When I'm at work I do use a tenkeyless keyboard (no numpad) and a magic touchpad right next to it, so the ergonomics are decent enough. Similarly if on most laptops. But at the desktop with a mouse this still sort of sucks.

Comment: Yeah. I used [this](https://github.com/bbeck/keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-search) extension before, worked like a charm, but then stopped working because Google changed the results page a bit I guess. Could be easy to fix :/ I tried a while ago, but my javascript/DOM wasn't quite at the level then. Resolved to using the *Vimium* extension. But never really liked that approach. So yesterday I gave up and turned the damn *Instant* on. Might try fixing that *keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-search* extension again when I catch a bit of time

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but have you tried [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb). It uses a similar approach to the vim editor

Comment: The google instant search keyboard navigation has now been disabled permanently :( See my new question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1234766/how-to-use-keyboard-to-navigate-google-search-results-now-that-instant-search-i

Answer (score 0):

I think [Gleebox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gleebox/miinkdcjglbkbanpkghnkgkgbamdkgji?hl=en) will do what you need. Simply set your shortcut to invoke it, and type '2' on a google search page and hit enter.

If you're in an input field, use alt+ [whatever your binding is in extenstion-->settings] and it will auto escape you from that field to allow you to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following Chrome extension: [Google Search Shortcuts - RESULTER](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-shortcuts-r/chojfhfgbdaeokblbdeahgbijodikdpk).

Some of the functions:

- Tab/Keys for results navigation
- Alt+1..9 to open the N-th result
- Alt+S to focus on the search box
- Alt+A to open search results list

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Well, I added the list of features, not much more I can do probably