# Google instant stopped working

Tags: google-search

Since yesterday, my google instant search option dissappeared (Chrome).
When I write something it won't show the options to fill the search bar.
When I hit enter it takes a lot more time to get results, and even mentions for a second that google instant is not available.
When the results come in, the layout is different, the links are underlined for some reason, and it is not showing pictures unless I directly go to the pictures tab, and even than the layout is a lot different.

System: Win 10 Professional 64 bit 
Web browser: Google Chrome

I keep my PC "clean" with Defender, Malwarebytes (Antimalware and Anti-exploit Premium) and CCleaner, regularly clean the browsing cache, never had any problems for years.

Comment: To get better traction on this question, you should specifically address what steps you've taken to resolve this issue.  Spell out exactly what the expected behavior is and how it's different now (screenshots would be helpful).  If you've Googled a suggested fix, but it didn't work, you should mention that.  As it stands right now, your question is too open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that [Google Instant has been discontinued.](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/news/google-instant-search-discontinued-unified-design-mobile-desktop-1729717) On the plus side this means you can eliminate computer virus infection as the cause to your web searching woes. On the down side, it isn't coming back and much of this functionality is now gone.

Some of the features, in particular being able to use arrow keys to navigate search results, has been asked about [here](https://superuser.com/questions/509192/tab-enter-no-longer-taking-me-to-first-google-search-result-in-chrome) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1234766/how-to-use-keyboard-to-navigate-google-search-results-now-that-instant-search-i/1235053#1235053). The solution to being able to navigate using arrow keys (up and down) is given [here](https://superuser.com/a/1235053/208025).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Go to setting

[image]

Next find search engine and change it on google or if you dont have google engine add this In the window which you see :)

[image]

Comment: -1 You should answer questions in English for this site.

Comment: That feature no longer exists!!!

Comment: @Robino Hmmm... Maybe You are a little bit blind but important options has been translate on English using red color