# Are there any keyboard shortcuts for the Google search page?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

I really hate having to leave my keyboard to select links after a Google search.  Are there any keyboard shortcuts built in to the Google search page?

A while back, I seem to remember being able to tab directly from one result to another, but I don't seem to be able to do this anymore.

Comment: general keyboard navigation for your browser? tabs & enter used to work... An addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work exactly as you describe it: enter the search term, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus on the search results. Press <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to select a result, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it.

Comment: Hmm, not working for me.  Tab-ing after a search walks through all the links above the search results (like the Google+ notification links and the `Web`, `Maps`, `Shopping`, etc. links).

Comment: According to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/410817/65572), you might need to have Google instant enabled for this to work.

Comment: Yep, enabling Google instant was the trick.  Thanks!  Although I wish there was a way to use the shortcuts without instant...

Answer (score 2):

To access the list of result provided by the Google search,

You can use shift + down arrow or up-arrow key to select the search topic and then you can use Return to Keyboard button on the   topic to open the link in new tab as per your need.

Comment: You don't even need the shift key - just press down arrow and the first result is selected.

Comment: And now seems changed again, arrow keys now scroll the page. Very frustrating.