# Prevent Google Search from focusing on search box on (almost) every key

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, safari, google-search

The opposite question ([Is there keyboard shortcut to move input focus to the Google Search box?](https://superuser.com/questions/410813/is-there-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-input-focus-to-the-google-search-box)) has the accepted answer that amounts to "... just begin typing again".

How can you *prevent* this? I'd like to re-enter the search box only manually, using only a *specific* shortcut (e.g. <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd>) and still be able use a type-to-navigate browser extension.

I'm mostly interested in `Safari`, but a general answer would be welcome as well, since the default behaviour is the same also in `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

### Safari

For `Safari`, this [NinjaKit](https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit) script should [disable hotkeys on StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179168/176141):

```
(typeof unsafeWindow !== 'undefined' ? unsafeWindow : window).$(function() {
  var p = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
  if (!p) 
    return;
  p = p.parentNode;
  function ignore(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }    
  p.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
  p.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
  p.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
});
```

**What is the equivalent of StackExchange's `'wmd-input'` in Google Search `.js`?** I don't know where to look in their `.js` files, since it's all obfuscated. For instance, there's this:

```
_.um = function(a) {
        if (48 <= a && 57 >= a || 96 <= a && 106 >= a || 65 <= a && 90 >= a || _.Pb && 0 == a) return !0;
        switch (a) {
            case 32:
            case 63:
            case 107:
            case 109:
            case 110:
            case 111:
            case 186:
            case 59:
            case 189:
            case 187:
            case 61:
            case 188:
            case 190:
            case 191:
            case 192:
            case 222:
            case 219:
            case 220:
            case 221:
                return !0;
            default:
                return !1
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in `chrome://flags` disable the `Enable distance field text` flag.

Comment: In `chrome://flags` I only find this: `**Enable distance field text**:
If enabled, text is rendered with signed distance fields rather than bitmap alpha masks.`

Comment: that is it, it  allows  it to make it like a "clickable" not always there

Comment: Didn't work for me: disabled the above flag, restarted (the latest) Chrome, and Google search box still refocuses on every key/letter.

Comment: what is 'answers in search' set to?

Comment: It seems that the `Answers in Suggest` flag isn't available on OS X: `Sorry, this experiment is not available on your platform.` I presume then that your answer is working on Linux and Windows, but not (yet) on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/tBTtSNeyIjc) forum, there is a firefox addon called GoogleEnhancer that has this as a side effect.